# Retagging between turing-machines, turing-machine, turing

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request

Three SO tags for which the wiki excerpts are basically exact matches:

- [turing-machines](/questions/tagged/turing-machines): 134 questions, 32 followers, excerpt: "A Turing machine is an idealized model of computation..."
- <del>[turing-machine](/questions/tagged/turing-machine): 3 questions, 3 followers, excerpt: "A Turing machine is a device that manipulates symbols..."</del>
- [turing](/questions/tagged/turing): 19 questions, 14 followers, excerpt: "Known as turing machine, it is a device that manipulates symbols..."

Though the other two are much less popular, a few [highly-voted but possibly non-constructive questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/235984/the-halting-problem-in-the-field) use the [other forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236000/whats-a-turing-machine).

The two that just differ by a plural are easy, and it's obvious that the plural form is the more popular one. Just [turing](/questions/tagged/turing) is a little more difficult, as it could theoretically be a holding place for [turing-machine](/questions/tagged/turing-machine), [turing-complete](/questions/tagged/turing-complete), the Turing test, [the Turing language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2018414/need-help-with-counted-loops-in-turing), or fanfiction about Alan Turing (maybe not so much the last one).

As far as I can tell, there's a mere one question about the language Turing, the one linked in the previous paragraph. I don't believe that really warrants keeping [turing](/questions/tagged/turing) around, but the few Turing test questions don't seem to have a home other than [artificial-intelligence](/questions/tagged/artificial-intelligence).

Manually moving nearly all the questions from the other two tags to [turing-machines](/questions/tagged/turing-machines) would be easy. As I understand it, if [turing-machine](/questions/tagged/turing-machine) goes away, users wouldn't be able to recreate it, as it differs only by a trailing s?

Comment: In the realm of Turing things, there's also [turing-tarpit], which doesn't seem to need to exist at all, though I'm a fan of the term.

Comment: [turing-machine] as a singular collective noun seems like it would be the proper tag name, such as other tags like [iphone] covering all iPhones in existence

Comment: I don't think either "iPhone" or "Turing machine" are collective nouns, they're just singular. Anyway, since there's a mixture of singular, plural, gerund, etc. all over the place, I assume custom and popularity rule the day. Plus, it's easier to move just 3 questions.

Comment: Fair, might as well go with what's most popular